# Database communication link error occurded on Azure ML Service (Used Azure SQL Server DB)

Tags: python, database, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I have used Azure Machine Learning Service and python programming language.  On Azure Machine Learning Service I have one python script in that script there is one normal Select query. whenever I have deploy models on azure then that time I got ML endpoint.  whenever i am posting input data on ML endpoint then i got **('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')** error.

Also, I have used azure SQL Server Database.

I am not able to understand why I got this error.  Is there any reason for this error?

Comment: have you tried registering the query as a Dataset in the UI? I'd like to help you understand if it is a problem with Azure SQL or with Azure ML.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below snapshots and the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-datasets#access-datasets-in-your-script) to register database with the azure ml service.
[image]

[image]

[image]